# iFrame is not displaying properly when updated by JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

For some weird reason, iFrame is not showing the right content when updated by JavaScript. It is the very same link, but with different results

https://jsfiddle.net/omarjuvera/qvbpcy9k/1/

**HTML**

```
Desired result
<br/>
<iframe src="//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&amp;OneJS=1&amp;Operation=GetAdHtml&amp;MarketPlace=US&amp;source=ac&amp;ref=tf_til&amp;ad_type=product_link&amp;tracking_id=ow-20&amp;marketplace=amazon&amp;region=US&amp;placement=B004BCXAM8&amp;asins=B004BCXAM8&amp;linkId=SK5UG2J5CK4WNOKE&amp;show_border=true&amp;link_opens_in_new_window=true"></iframe>

<br/><br/>
JavaScript update
<br/>
<iframe id=link src=""></iframe>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("link").src = '//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&amp;OneJS=1&amp;Operation=GetAdHtml&amp;MarketPlace=US&amp;source=ac&amp;ref=tf_til&amp;ad_type=product_link&amp;tracking_id=ow-20&amp;marketplace=amazon&amp;region=US&amp;placement=B004BCXAM8&amp;asins=B004BCXAM8&amp;linkId=SK5UG2J5CK4WNOKE&amp;show_border=true&amp;link_opens_in_new_window=true';
```

Comment: I don't see content in either iframe in the jsfiddle. What is supposed to be there?

Comment: @firefoxuser-1 The first one has a mascara, from amazon

Answer (score 2):

For some reason your ampersands are & amp; just make them &. It seems like the static code fixed the problem for you internally but the javascript did not.

```
document.getElementById("link").src = 
'//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&OneJS=1&Operation=GetAdHtml&MarketPlace=US&source=ac&ref=tf_til&ad_type=product_link&tracking_id=ow-20&marketplace=amazon&region=US&placement=B004BCXAM8&asins=B004BCXAM8&linkId=SK5UG2J5CK4WNOKE&show_border=true&link_opens_in_new_window=true'
```

Comment: How do I go about replacing them all in JavaScript?

Comment: I need JavaScript to do all the work, instead of manually replacing each & amp

Comment: `document.getElementById("link").src = ('//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&amp;OneJS=1&amp;Operation=GetAdHtml&amp;MarketPlace=US&amp;source=ac&amp;ref=tf_til&amp;ad_type=product_link&amp;tracking_id=ow-20&amp;marketplace=amazon&amp;region=US&amp;placement=B004BCXAM8&amp;asins=B004BCXAM8&amp;linkId=SK5UG2J5CK4WNOKE&amp;show_border=true&amp;link_opens_in_new_window=true').replace(/amp;/g, '');`

Comment: O.o That's a mouthful comment :p  Why not edit your answer, and/or add a fiddle?